# Initialising an array of pointers to structs in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null, initialization

I have an array of pointers to structs. I want to initialise every element in the array to NULL. I'm going to use this array to dynamically add and remove entries so I want to be able to test against NULL to see if that index is empty.

I tried to do it like this:

```
struct mystructure *cxs[MAXNOCXS];

int cx_init(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<MAXNOCXS; i++)
        cxs[i] == NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

but my compiler tells me:

```
error: statement with no effect
```

referring to the line `cxs[i] = NULL;`

Are arrays of pointers automatically initialised to NULL in C? If not how could I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the `==` operator instead of the `=` operator. In practice, instead of assigning `NULL` to `cxs[i]` (which is what it would do if you used the assignment operator `=`) you are comparing each element with `NULL` and discarding the result of such comparison, thus the warning of your compiler.

Notice that you can initialize more simply your array using the notation

```
struct mystructure * cxs[MAXNOCXS] = {};
```

This syntax tells to the compiler to default-initialize<sup>1</sup> all the elements of the array (since the braces, that would contain explicit initializers, are empty), which means that pointers get initialized to `NULL` and arithmetic types to 0.

If your array has "static storage duration" (i.e. it's a global or `static` variable), you don't need to do anything special because it's already default-initialized.

---

1. To the value they would be initialized to if they were `static` variables (C99, §6.7.8 ¶10, ¶21).

---

***Edit***

After reading around, it seems that the C standard, unlike the C++ one, do not support empty initializers. Still, you can always do:

```
struct mystructure * cxs[MAXNOCXS] = {NULL};
```

which will initialize the first element with `NULL`, and let the other elements be default-initialized (again to `NULL`).

Comment: Assuming these variables are in global scope, they are default-initialised even if they're not `static`.  Also, I don't think the standard permits empty initializer lists.

Comment: @Oli: correct about `static`, I was coming from the standard that says *static storage duration*, which is a different thing, now I correct it. For the empty initializer list, I checked on the fly with gcc 4.5 with `-ansi -Wall -Wextra` and it didn't complain, now I'll check the standard...

Comment: Thanks for the great answers, I should have noticed the typo myself. Also worth noting @Oli's comment that my global variable will already be initialised.

Comment: @Oli: apparently you were right, the syntax description in the standard seems not to allow empty initializer lists, and a quick search seem to confirm this fact.

Comment: Yeah, the grammar definition appears to prohibit it.

Answer (score 2):

You will notice that your line is `cxs[i] == NULL;`, and not `cxs[i] = NULL;` as you intended.

Also, as it appears that your array has been declared at global scope (and therefore has *static storage duration*), it will have all its elements zero-initialised by default, so the pointers will already all equal `NULL`.  (Note that this most definitely *not* the case for standard local variables inside functions).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a typo in your code and accidentally use comparison operator instead of assignment - that's what compiler tells you about

```
for (i=0; i<MAXNOCXS; i++)
        cxs[i] == NULL;
```

should be

```
for (i=0; i<MAXNOCXS; i++)
        cxs[i] = NULL;
```